# When asserting that an element is found is using .exists necessary?

Tags: automated-tests, selector, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

It seems that,

`t.expect(Selector("[data-testid='foo']")).ok();`

and,

`t.expect(Selector("[data-testid='foo']").exists).ok();`

result in the same outcome so is `.exists` necessary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Selector("[data-testid='foo']")` returns a Promise. 
The `t.expect(Selector("[data-testid='foo']")).ok();` assertion will always pass regardless of whether there is an element on the page or not. It happens because a Promise instance will be cast to `true`.

`t.expect(Selector("[data-testid='foo']").exists).ok();` is the correct assertion. It checks an element on the page using the [Smart assertion query mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/#smart-assertion-query-mechanism)